# Angularjs: run jquery after load in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Hi How to run jquery scripts when I load data in ng-repeat.
jquery works good when I have a static dom element, but when I use ng-repeat scripts not working I need to use dynamically height of div, and bootstrap tooltip. I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //myMovies
        //$('.templates_movies').height($('.templates').outerHeight());
    $(document).on("load", ".templates_movies", function() {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });


});
```

But it's not working. Please help me.

Comment: you have to create a directive for that

Answer (score 1):

you can create directive

```
app.directive("tooltip",function(){
  return{
    link: function(scope,ele,attr){
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
    }
  }
});
```

and then use "tooltip" with your ng-repeat like

```
<div ng-repeat ="item in [1,2,3]" tooltip>
   <span data-toggle="tooltip"  class="test" title="Hiiii" ng-bind="item"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: i include: <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: i do that i have first app.controller(...).directive()

Comment: Try my new updated code under directive link function "$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); ". I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

An example of the link function of the directive would be:

```
function link (scope, element) {
  $(element[0].querySelectorAll('[data-toggle="tooltip"]')).tooltip();
}
```